# pdftk watermark above page

Tags: php, pdftk

I'm using pdftk to fill a pdf form with an xfdf file.
Once this is done I use another pdf (containing a big red "SPECIMEN") as a watermark with the following command :

```
shell_exec(SOURCE_PDF stamp WATERMARK_PDF output - flatten);
```

The result is good, all the pages have the watermark.
However, the dynamic content in the form fields is displayed above the specimen.

I find nothing about this problem in the documentation or even stackoverflow.

Do you know if I can force the watermark to be on the top ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved. For information, in order to apply a watermark above a dynamic form you MUST flatten it BEFORE.
When it's basic text you can do what you want.